# using reduce to flatten array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm getting a little confused with using reduce.

it's array.reduce((accumulator, value) => do something with accumulator, why is this returning back an empty array?

```js
let a = [
  [1,2],
  [
    [3,4]
  ],
  [
    [[5],[6]]
  ]
];

const flatten = arr => arr.reduce((a, v) => {
  v instanceof Array ? flatten(v) : a.push(v);
  return a;
}, [])


console.log(flatten(a));
```

Comment: Is there a reason `Array.prototype.flat()` or `Array.prototype.flatMap()` is not being used?

Comment: I'm learning how to use reduce. but good to know there is a native method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `flatten(v)` returns an array, but you're not doing anything with it currently. Try pushing the spread array into the accumulator instead:

```js
let a = [
  [1,2],
  [
    [3,4]
  ],
  [
    [[5],[6]]
  ]
];

const flatten = arr => arr.reduce((a, v) => {
  v instanceof Array ? a.push(...flatten(v)) : a.push(v);
  return a;
}, [])


console.log(flatten(a));
```

Or, you can use `concat`, and only use the conditional operator when you need the entire thing to resolve to an *expression* (don't use it as an alternative to `if`/`else`):

```js
let a = [
  [1,2],
  [
    [3,4]
  ],
  [
    [[5],[6]]
  ]
];

const flatten = arr => arr.reduce((a, v) => {
  if (v instanceof Array) {
    return a.concat(flatten(v))
  } else {
    a.push(v);
    return a;
  }
}, [])


console.log(flatten(a));
```

Comment: ahh. so pushing to the accumulator has to all happen in the same loop

Comment: Either that, or pass the accumulator array around to each recursive call

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = [[1,2],[[3,4]],[[[5],[6]]]];

const flattenArr = (arr) => 
  arr.reduce((acc, val) => 
   Array.isArray(val) ? 
    acc.concat(flattenArr(val)) :
     acc.concat(val), []);
 
console.log(flattenArr(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let array = [[2, 4, 6, 8], [10, 12, 14], [16, 18, 20, 22]]

const flatten = array.reduce((a, b) => {
  return a.concat(b)
})

console.log(flatten)
```

`.concat` concatenates two arrays, `reduce` does a loop under the hood and concatenation results in flattening.

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.